# Display an integer array in a random order without using shuffle

Tags: c#

```
        int n;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a positive integer for the array size"); // asking the user for the int n

        n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] array = new int[n]; // declaring the array
        int[] newarray = new int[n];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = i + 1;
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < newarray.Length; y++)
        {
            int caseSwitch = 1;
            switch (caseSwitch)
            {
                case 1:
                    newarray[y] = array[rand.Next(n)];
                    goto case 2;
                case 2:
                    for (int z = y+1; z > 0; z--)
                    {
                        if (newarray[y] == newarray[z-1])
                            goto case 1;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        for (int x=0;x<newarray.Length;x++)
        {
            Console.Write(" {0}", newarray[x]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

This is the code i have started with but its not displaying any values, is it not filling the array? I'm new to this so any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Oh come on ! Why using **goto** in C# ? :(

Comment: that's one of the few generally accepted uses of `goto` @JustinIurman

Comment: @JustinIurman, there are actually a few cases where it makes sense. For instance, implicit fallthrough between cases in a switch statement is not allowed, but if you want to do it explicitly, you can use `goto case 2`. But I agree that the second goto in the code above is a bit ugly...

Comment: Yes but i keep thinking it's not elegant

Comment: I trully don't understand the question. What is the objective?

Comment: `newarray[y] = array[rand.Next(n)];` This could choose the same element multiple times.

Comment: Do you really even need to create your initial array here?

Comment: Do you want to randomize the array with or without duplicates? I have no idea what "without using shuffle" means.

Comment: Why do you not want to use shuffle? Is it (1) because you don't want to change the original array, or (2) because this is a homework question, or (3) for a learning exercise (see (2))?

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is extremely overly complicated for this. You should take a step back, think about what it is that you wish to accomplish, plan it out first, then start programming.

What you want to do is sort your array with a random sort order.

Create a new `IComparer` that returns the comparison randomly:

```
public class RandomComparer<T> : IComparer<T> {
    private static Random random = new Random();

    public int Compare(T a, T b) {
        return random.Next(2) == 0 ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

Now, sort your array:

```
int[] array = {
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
    6, 7, 8, 9, 10
};

Array.Sort<int>(array, new RandomComparer<int>());

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
```

It's really that simple. See this demonstration at [IDEOne.com](http://ideone.com/4XTZAg)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
...

n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

// Initial array filled with 1..n values
int[] data = Enumerable.Range(1, n).ToArray(); 
// data array indice to show, initially 0..n-1
List<int> indice = Enumerable.Range(0, n - 1).ToList(); 

Random gen = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  if (i != 0)
    Console.Write(' ');

  index = gen.Next(indice.Count);

  Console.Write(data[indice[index]]);
  // Index has been shown, let's remove it since we're not going to show it again 
  indice.RemoveAt(index);
}    

...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to get into an infinite loop. Try changing this bit:

```
        case 2:
                for (int z = y; z > 0; z--)
                {
                    if (newarray[y] == newarray[z-1])
                        goto case 1;
                }
                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not seeing any output is because the code isn't running to completion - it ends up bouncing between case 1 and 2 because

```
if (newarray[y] == newarray[z - 1])
```

is always true.

My recommendation would be to debug (i.e. step through) your code so you can really see why this is the case, then you'll be able to fix the code yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to generate a random permutation. You could try the following:

```
var rand = new Random();
var left = Enumerable.Range(1, n).ToList();
for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
{
   int j = rand.Next(n-i);
   Console.Out.WriteLine(left[j]);
   left[j].RemoveAt(j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to do it using a random comparison.

```
class Program
{
    static Random rnd=new Random();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array= { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        int[] newarray=new int[array.Length];
        array.CopyTo(newarray, 0);
        Array.Sort(newarray, (i, j) => rnd.NextDouble()<0.5?-1:1);            
        // newarray is now randomly ordered
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can randomly switch the values :

```
int n;
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a positive integer for the array size"); // asking the user for the int n
n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

int[] array = new int[n]; // declaring the array
int[] newarray = new int[n];
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    array[i] = i + 1;
    newarray[i] = i + 1;
}
for (int y = 0; y < newarray.Length; y++)
{
    int r = rand.Next(n);
    int tmp = newarray[y];
    newarray[y] = newarray[r];
    newarray[r] = tmp;
}

for (int x=0;x<newarray.Length;x++)
{
    Console.Write(" {0}", newarray[x]);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Isn't this shuffling?

Comment: Yep =) I thought there was an existing shuffle method, like in Java, that he didn't want to use. And since he himself kind of shuffle in his code...

Comment: My point is if the framework already have a built-in sort function why built your own, and a buggy one too. `r` can have duplicates above. Also why write a `CopyTo()` loop instead of use the built-in functions  under `System.Array`

Comment: It doesn't matter if r has duplicates since it's used as an index to switch values. And the loop was only to follow his own code

Comment: It does because it is not guaranteed to touch every element of the array. The results are not random. See comments on slash shogdhe's answer.

Comment: Each element will change position at least once

Comment: Ok it'll not change in this case but it'll be touched as you said. When shuffling some elements can remain on the same position

Answer (score -1):

use following code

```
   int[] array = new int[n];
        int[] randomPosition = new int[n];
        Enumerable.Range(0, n ).ToList().ForEach(o => array[o] = o+1);
        Random r = new Random();
        Enumerable.Range(0, n).ToList().ForEach(o => randomPosition[o] = r.Next(0, n - 1));
        foreach (var m in randomPosition)
        {
          var randomNumber =   array[m];
          //write randomnumber
        }
```

Comment: This does not display the array in a random order.  It displays random elements from the array, most likely with duplicates.  Also, `array` can be initialized in a simpler way: `array = Enumerable.Range( 1, n ).ToArray();`

Comment: Can you please explain the condition for "most likely with duplicates"

Comment: The `randomPosition` array is merely being populated with random integers from the range [0, n).  `Random.Next` does not make sure that those calls result in unique values, it's perfectly fine repeating values that it's already given.

Comment: sorry, only condition Random wont give you unique number if you reinitialize it on every itration, actually it calculate value on the base of seeds

Comment: Yes, I know how `Random.Next` works and calling it n times consecutively *will not* produce the integers [0, n) in a random order.  The method attempts to model a uniform distribution where each call is independent of the last.  It is perfectly possible and reasonable for two consecutive calls to `Random.Next` to give the same result.  In this case the calls don't even need to be consecutive, you just need to get the same number twice within the sequence.  The odds of getting at least one number twice in your sequence should be 1 - n! / n^n, which is a value that very rapidly approaches 1.

Comment: For example, if you create `var rng = new Random(12345);` and then call `rng.Next(10)` five times, it returns `0, 0, 7, 5, 7` with 0 and 7 both duplicated twice!

Comment: but I am not passing seed in Random,its new Random() not new Random(12345)

Comment: @slashshogdhe That makes no difference! It can still produce duplicates! Think about it for a second. It's like rolling a dice. If you roll a dice 4 times, can you roll a six twice? Yes! Random() works the same way.

Comment: Matthew Watson-- I have written a complete housie game on random keyword for my client before 3 years, it not producing single duplicate value.

Comment: ok give me the code without seed and using same instance of random  that creating duplicate number

Comment: well please don't take it as a fight, this is all about knowledge and learning..

Comment: @slashshogdhe Leaving the seed out of the constructor just causes the seed to be set based on the system time.  It's no different than setting the seed explicitly.  It's trivially easy to test this: `var rng = new Random(); var numbers = Enumerable.Range( 0, 10 ).Select( i => rng.Next( 10 ) ); foreach( var n in numbers ) Console.WriteLine( n );`  There's greater than a 99% chance that that will produce duplicates.

Comment: matthwe -- Kyle-- thankyou very much for sharing your knowledge. well I have checked the code of housie game also I have a guard condition on generating random number. At last you are right...